# Shape of the LSTM layers in multilayer LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(tokenizer.vocab_size, 64),tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,return_sequences=True))     
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

The second layer has 64 hidden units and since the return_sequences=True, it will output 64 sequences as well. But how can it be fed to a 32 hidden units LSTM. Won't it cause shape mismatch error?

Answer (score 0):

Actually no, it won't cause it. First of all the second layer won't have the output shape of `64`, but instead of `128`. This is because you are using `Bidirectional` layer, it will be concatenated by a forward and backward pass and so you output will be `(None, None, 64+64=128)`. You can refer to the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Bidirectional).

The `RNN` data is shaped in the following was `(Batch_size, time_steps, number_of_features)`. This means when you try to connect two layer with different neurons the features increased or decreased based on the number of neurons.You can follow the particular link for more [details](https://github.com/MohammadFneish7/Keras_LSTM_Diagram).

And for your particular code this is how the model summary will look like. So to answer in short their won't be a mismatch.

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 64)          32000     
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, None, 128)         66048     
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 64)                41216     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 143,489
Trainable params: 143,489
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: "This means when you try to connect two layer with different neurons the features increased or decreased based on the number of neurons"
I didnt get this statement

Comment: ohh okay got it. So basically if i have 10 features in input data but the neurons I have set as 8. will it disgard the remaining 2 features?